# First Letter Capitalization in CakePHP Model Name

Tags: php, cakephp

I have been having a problem lately with my CakePHP models. The capitalization of the first letter of the model name keep changing. For example

```
$brands = $this->brand->findAllByCompanyId($company);
$list = array();
foreach ($brands as &$brand) {
    $list[] = array(
        'name' => $brand['brand']['name'],
        'id'   => $brand['brand']['id']
    );
}
```

For some reason, the key names would change to

```
$brand['Brand']['name']
$brand['Brand']['id']
```

Notice the change in the capitalization in the word "Brand." Does anyone have an idea why this happens, or how to force a specific capitalization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the [basic principles of CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/view/892/Basic-Principles-of-CakePHP) is about making life easier by [following conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/22/CakePHP-Conventions). As @Neal above says, CakePHP expects the Model to be capitalised. Stick to it being capitalised and you'll make your life easier.

Comment: It looks like my $uses line referenced a lowercase name of the model. It still worked, but certainly did not make my life easier. By making it uppercase, it seems to have solved the issue. The model names no longer switch back and forth

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP models **always** capitalizes the name of the model when it is selecting it from the database.
(I am assuming that `$this->brand->findAllByCompanyId($company);` is doing a query)

Comment: It seems this is not the case. The code that I posted is what is currently working in my script, $brand['brand']['name'] has no capitals. But recently I had to use $brand['Brand']['name'].

Answer (score 1):

You can override this by adding the line in your `model`.

`$this->name = 'brand';`

Comment: but i would stick to the convention and use "Brand". like everyone else :)